# python рекурсия

Tags: python, pyqt, рекурсия

Есть список, который надо проверить. Есть кнопка.
При нажатии на кнопку проваливаемся в `button_clicked`. Там все работает. При вызове рекурсии (`rekursia`) программа крашится даже не войдя в нее

```
def add_functions(self):
    self.btn_green_1p.clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_clicked(1))


def rekursia(self,i, j, color):
    print("fa")
    #color: 1 - green, 2 - red, 3 - yellow, 4 - blue, 5 - black
    if table2[i-1][j] == color and i >= 0 :
        print("fa1")
        print(f'{i}{j}', i, j)
        self.rekursia(self, i-1, j, color)
        print("fa")


def button_clicked(self, color):
    for row in range(30):
        for col in range(30):
            if table2[row][col] == 1:
                print(table2[row][col])
                print(row)
                print(col)
                print(color)
                self.rekursia(self, row, col, color)
```

пробовал `self.rekursia(self, lambda: row, lambda: col, lambda: color)` не помогло.

Comment: Откуда у вас self?

Comment: @Александр в каком именно моменте?

Может быть будет понятнее, если я скажу, что это Pyqt?

Comment: Ах это ещё и PyQt?

Comment: @Александр Все верно

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вы передаете self в функцию?

```
self.rekursia(self, i-1, j, color)
```

self передастся автоматически, так как класс уже инициализирован

```
self.rekursia(i-1, j, color)
```

Comment: А можете чутка подробней объяснить зачем нам вообще нужен селф и где и когда он используется? немного путаюсь

Comment: self это ключевое слово указывающее на ваш класс. Давайте разберем на примере: допустим у вас есть класс `class Foo` который имеет две атрибуты `def say_hello(self)` и `def say_again(self)`. Первая атрибута будет печатать "Hello". Создадим экземпляр класса `main = Foo()` чтобы напечатать это "Hello" мы возьмем и напишем так `main.say_hello()`. self это тоже самое, что и main. self объединяет в себе все переменные и атрибуты в один объект. Теперь чтобы реализовать `say_again` вместо того чтобы снова написать `print("Hello")` мы можем обратится к уже реализованной функции `self.say_hello()`